# Applications of coclass theory 

Tags: gr.group-theory

If $G$ is a $p$-group of order $p^n$ and class $c$ then its *coclass* is $n-c$. In 1980 Leedham-Green and Newman initiated an investigation of $p$-groups with fixed coclass by formulating a couple of conjectures. These had been proved till 1990 by various contributors.

To give an example, the strongest result in this frame states that there is a function $f(p,r)$ depending only on $p$ and the coclass $r$ such that every $p$-group $G$ of coclass $r$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of class $\le 2$ and $(G:N) \le f(p,r)$ (in case $p=2,\; N$ can be choosen to be abelian).

Applications of this coclass theory, I've seen, are are two results of Eick, both for $p=2$:

- Up to a finite number of groups, all $2$-groups of a fixed coclass can be described by a finite number of paramerized presentations.
- Almost all $2$-groups of a fixed coclass satisfy the divisibility conjecture (i.e. $|G|$ divides $|Aut(G)|$ for all $p$-groups $G$).

**Question:** Are there other applications of coclass theory in group theory or other branches in mathematics known ?